# Two Column Inequality Proof

Tags: inequality

I'm an absolute beginner in proving so I need help please.
Let $a$ and $b$ be both positive numbers. If $a \gt b$, then $a^2\gt b^2$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ so will be positive if...